# Bluemix IBM Insights for Twitter Service - real time data

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

According to the documentation from the twitter service:
Use IBM® Insights for Twitter to incorporate Twitter content from the Twitter Decahose into your IBM Bluemix™ applications. The content store is refreshed and indexed in real-time, making searches dynamic and fast. The service enriches Tweets with sentiment and other insights for multiple languages, based on deep natural language processing algorithms from IBM Social Media Analytics.

But whatever queries we run, the data returned is always 2-3 days old. We are not getting latest real time data. How do we get real time data with the Insights for twitter service?

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: No This seems like a intermittent problem, we do not have this problem anymore.